# if, elif & !=, == boolean operations only return "false" with inputs

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, input, boolean

I am creating an Among Us ripoff (for fun!) and the while True & if/elif/else statements will only return false (not An Impostor) with the inputs. I had created a list for the names and 2 random elements from the list will be chosen as **An Impostor**. However, whenever I input a name that is **The Impostor**, it will only return

> (player) was not An Impostor.

Here is my code;

```
import sys, time, random
names = ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4", "player5", "player6", "player7", "player8", "player9", "player10"]
print("Players: ")
for x in names:
  print(x)
print('—————————————————————————')
impostor1 = random.choice(names)
impostor2 = random.choice(names)
crewmates = 8
impostors = 2
tries = 6
while True:
  talk = input("Guess who The Impostor(s) are. " + str(crewmates) + " Crewmates are left. " + str(impostors) + " Impostors are left. You have " + str(tries) + " tries left.")
  if talk in names:
    print(talk + " was voted for.")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if talk != impostor1 or talk != impostor2:
      notimp = talk + " was not An Impostor. "
      names.remove(talk)
      for y in notimp:
        sys.stdout.write(y)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.05)
      crewmates -= 1
      tries -= 1
    elif talk == impostor1 or talk == impostor2:
      wasimp = talk + " was An Impostor. "
      names.remove(talk)
      for v in wasimp:
        sys.stdout.write(v)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
      impostors -= 1
  else:
    print("That player was either ejected or is not a valid player.")
```

However, whenever I put the Impostor in the input, it says it isn't An Impostor?

Comment: Oh, and if you need a more cleaned up version of the code, I can give. I just need to know what I'm doing wrong with these if statements, I don't need rewritten code.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  You posted 30 lines of code for a 3-line question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is the source of the problem:

`if talk != impostor1 or talk != impostor2:`

Let's say `impostor1` is player1 and `impostor2` is player2 and someone `input` in player1, according to Python `Boolean` expression operator `or` that `if` statement will evaluate like this:

`if player1 != impostor1` evaluated to `False` because player1 is indeed equals to `impostor1`.

So far so good, but because the first test is a `False`, Python simply evaluates and returns the right side operand which may be either `True` or `False`. In your case Python will evaluate `if talk != impostor2` and return `True`, thereafter executes the nested block.